# What is more secure, JWT in HTTP sessions or JWT in client's request header?

Tags: node.js, http, jwt, httpsession, express-jwt

I am trying to implement JWT based authentication system in one of my project and I have stuck between two option where I need some clarifications. I have come up with two approaches for implementing JWT as follows:

### Approach 1

- Client sends credentials for login
- Server verifies the credentials
- Server Generates two tokens, auth-token and refresh-token
- Server stores these token into it's redis-server as [key]=refresh-token and [value]=auth-token
- Since HTTP connections are always alive between client and server, the Server sets the auth-token into the http-sessions and send refresh-token in response.
- Client stores the refresh-token into local browser storage and use it whenever the http connection is closed between client and server to regain authentication.
- Also, with the help of refresh-token we can refresh the auth-token easily without logging out the user.

### Approach 2

- Client sends credentials for login
- Server verifies the credentials
- Server generates auth-token and sends in response to the client
- Client set the token in the request header for each request it makes to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good explanation https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/

> Refresh Tokens are long-lived. This means when a client gets one from
>   a server, this token must be stored securely to keep it from being
>   used by potential attackers, for this reason, it is not safe to store
>   them in the browser. If a Refresh Token is leaked, it may be used to
>   obtain new Access Tokens (and access protected resources) until it is
>   blacklisted. Refresh Tokens must be issued to a single authenticated
>   client to prevent the use of leaked tokens by other parties. Access
>   Tokens must also be kept secret, but due to its shorter life, security
>   considerations are less critical.

Also a sessions may be hijacking or fixation done.

If you using SSL all the headers is encrypted.

So I'll prefer a native JWT mechanism and 'll pay attention to the storage of the auth token on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my clarifications,

- Storing sessions on browser side that are long lived is always risky
- Let the server do the JOB of verifying token sent by third party or application. This is make sure the token that is being sent is intact and valid.
- I will prefer approach for always sending token in headers over HTTPS. This make easy and more secured because server is going to validate your token w.r.t to user session.